# Usar una variable fuera del ciclo for

Tags: php

Hola tengo un ciclo for para saber las fechas que hay en medio de dos variables. 
una vez obtengo el resultado lo inserto en una tabla de mi base de datos, pero se hace una inserción por cada fecha intermedia. 
Así:

```
.....usuario..........................fecha1................intermedios...........fecha_2

usuario@hotmail.com.....2019-08-20...........2019-08-21........30-08-2019

usuario@hotmail.com......2019-08-20..........2019-08-22........30-08-2019

usuario@hotmail.com......2019-08-20..........2019-08-23........30-08-2019
```

Supongo que es por el bucle for.

Lo que quiero es que todas las fechas intermedias queden guardadas en un mismo campo.

Asi:

```
...........usuario...................fecha1...............................intermedios...............................fecha_2

usuario@hotmail.com.....2019-08-20...........2019-08-21 2019-08-22 2019-08-23 etc ..30-08-2019
```

¿Hay alguna forma de sacar el valor de la variable `$i` y así hacer la inserción de todas las fechas fuera del ciclo?.

De antemano gracias por su ayuda.

Acá esta mi código en `php`:

```
<?php
$fecha1 = "20-08-2019";
$fecha2 = "30-08-2019";


for($i=$fecha1;$i<=$fecha2;$i = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($i . " + 1 days"))){

     $i;
    include("abrir_conexion_2.php");

    $insercion = mysqli_query($conexion2, "INSERT INTO luis_florez_vargas_33 (usuario,fecha1,intermedios,fecha2) values ('usuario@hotmail.com','$fecha1','$i','$fecha2')");

    }

?>
```

Comment: Estás insertando los datos en el mismo campo siempre, en tu tabla usa un campo "ID", ya sea de auto-incremento, o que le asignes valor en la misma consulta.

Comment: Que deseas hacer?, tal vez estas enfocando mal la solución ya que insertarás muchos registros innecesarios a una tabla, tal vez debas hacer uso de un `between` si lo que quieres en consultar luego esa data por la fecha intermedio.

Comment: $fecha1 y $fecha2 no siempre van a ser iguales , creo q lo pusiste asi para el ejemplo,  si queres sacar el for podes hacer un if : if $fecha1<=$fecha2: $fecha_intermedia = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($fecha1 . " + 1 days")) else: $fecha_intermedia = $fecha1  y cuando haces el insert en vez que llamar a $i llamas a $fecha_intermedia $insercion = mysqli_query($conexion2, "INSERT INTO luis_florez_vargas_33 (usuario,fecha1,intermedios,fecha2) values ('usuario@hotmail.com','$fecha1','$fecha_intermedia','$fecha2')"); (Acomodalo a PHP q estoy con Python y ya no me acuerdo como se escribe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He estado un rato trabajando con tu código, y apenas he leído con más atención la parte "Lo que quiero es que todas las fechas intermedias queden guardadas en un mismo campo.", la mejor forma que he encontrado (al menos para mi) es dejar la inserción fuera del `for`, en el `for` sólo cambiar las fechas intermedias, por ejemplo así:

```
<?php
$fecha1 = "20-08-2019";
$fecha2 = "30-08-2019";
$intermedio = "";
for($i=date("d-m-Y", strtotime($fecha1 . " + 1 days"));$i<=$fecha2;$i = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($i . " + 1 days"))){
    if ($intermedio == ""){ //Colocamos este IF porque si no, nos colocaría una fecha vacía al inicio
        $intermedio = $i;
    }else {
    $intermedio = $intermedio . ", " . $i;
    echo $intermedio;
}}
    include("abrir_conexion_2.php");
    $insercion = mysqli_query($conexion2, "INSERT INTO luis_florez_vargas_33 (usuario,fecha1,intermedios,fecha2) values ('usuario@hotmail.com','$fecha1','$intermedio','$fecha2')");
?>
```

Como puedes ver, he hecho que empiece desde el primer día siguiente de la fecha inicial, declarando `$i=date("d-m-Y", strtotime($fecha1 . " + 1 days"))`, pero terminará en la fecha2 siempre.

Comment: Muchas gracias Carlos Alberto Marrufo, realmente me funciono!